# How to simulate stroke-align (stroke-alignment) in SVG

Tags: svg

I am trying to mimic the behavior of "stroke alignment" in an SVG object. While there is a [working draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-strokes/#SpecifyingStrokeAlignment) for `stroke-alignment` in the spec, this has not actually been implemented (despite being drafted in 2015).

Example of **non-working** `stroke-alignment`:

```html
The blue square should have stroke inside, the red outside, but they're both the same
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="100">
  <g id="myGroup" transform="translate(20 20)">
    <polygon id="myPoly0" points="0,0 50,0 50,50 0,50" style="fill:blue;stroke:black;stroke-width:4;stroke-alignment:inner"></polygon>
    <polygon id="myPoly1" transform="translate(75 0)" points="0,0 50,0 50,50 0,50" style="fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:4;stroke-alignment:outer"></polygon>
  </g>
</svg>
```

My approach to mimicking this behavior is to create a duplicate SVG object using the `<use>` element, setting a `stroke` property on the copy and scaling it *slightly* up or down depending on whether it's an *inner* or *outer* stroke alignment (default is center)

For example:

```html
The scale and transform for the &lt;use&gt; element gets worse the farther from origin

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="400">
  <g id="myGroup" style="fill:rgb(45, 130, 255);" transform="translate(20 20)">
    <polygon id="myPoly0" points="0,0 100,0 100,100 0,100"></polygon>
    <polygon id="myPoly1" transform="translate(110 110)" points="0,0 100,0 100,100 0,100"></polygon>
    <polygon id="myPoly2" transform="translate(220 220)" points="0,0 100,0 100,100 0,100"></polygon>

    <use id="myPolyCopy0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" href="#myPoly0" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:4;" transform="translate(-2 -2) scale(1.04 1.04)"></use>
    <use id="myPolyCopy1" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" href="#myPoly1" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:4;" transform="translate(-2 -2) scale(1.04 1.04)"></use>
    <use id="myPolyCopy2" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" href="#myPoly2" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:4;" transform="translate(-2 -2) scale(1.04 1.04)"></use>
  </g>
</svg>
```

As you can see from the above example, the relative positioning of the `<use>` element goes awry, and gets worse the farther away from the origin it gets.

Naively, I assume that the `transform` property of the `<use>` element acts upon the SVG shape referenced in its `href`, but that seems not to be the case.

In my example, I'm scaling a 100x100 square by a factor of 1.04, which should result in a 104x104 square (4px width of the stroke). I'm then translating *back* by -2px to position the stroke on the outside of the source shape, thereby mimicking an *outer* stroke alignment.

This works as expected if the source shape is at origin (relative to the container group), but goes bonkers if the source shape is translated away from the origin.

My brain says this should work, but my browser says no bueno.

Anyone got any clues?

Comment: Are you aware of the [`paint-order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/paint-order) presentation attribute? It will let you mimick the behavior of `stroke-alignment:outer` at least for fully-opaque colors.

Comment: @ccprog Yes I'm aware. Unfortunately it doesn't really offer a complete solution, and as you point out will only work in specific scenarios (also can't do "inner" alignment). But thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that the transform applied to the `<use>` element will be applied to the existing transform of the source element.

This means that the `scale` transform applied to the `<use>` element will *also* scale its `translate` matrix.

For example:

If the source element has `translate(100 100)`, applying a `scale(1.1 1.1)` on the `<use>` copy will *cause it* to have a translate with the value `(110,110)`

This means to move the copy with the stroke value back to the correct location, you need to move the copy far enough back to overcome this "scaled translation".

This may well be expected behavior, but it was not intuitive to me (I may need to RTFM). Overall this approach "works", but feels complicated and hacky.

Working sample:

```js
const strokeWidth = 8;

const poly1Translate = {
  x: 150,
  y: 20
};

const poly2Translate = {
  x: 300,
  y: 40
};

const poly1 = document.getElementById("myPoly1");
const poly2 = document.getElementById("myPoly2");

const polyCopy0 = document.getElementById("myPolyCopy0");
const polyCopy1 = document.getElementById("myPolyCopy1");
const polyCopy2 = document.getElementById("myPolyCopy2");

const styleString = `fill:none;stroke:red;stroke-opacity:0.5;stroke-width:${strokeWidth};`;

poly1.setAttribute(
  "transform",
  `translate(${poly1Translate.x} ${poly1Translate.y})`
);
poly2.setAttribute(
  "transform",
  `translate(${poly2Translate.x} ${poly2Translate.y})`
);

polyCopy0.setAttribute("style", styleString);
polyCopy1.setAttribute("style", styleString);
polyCopy2.setAttribute("style", styleString);

// Use the boundingbox to get the dimensions
const poly1BBox = poly1.getBBox();
const poly2BBox = poly2.getBBox();

let halfStrokeWidth = strokeWidth / 2;

// stroke-alignment:outside

// Scale the copy to be strokeWidth pixels larger
let scaleOutsideX = 1+strokeWidth/poly1BBox.width;
let scaleOutsideY = 1+strokeWidth/poly1BBox.height;

// Move the copy to the same scale property based on the current translation
// This will position the stroke at the correct origin point, and we need to 
// deduct a further half of the stroke width to position it fully on the outside
let translateOutsideX = -((poly1Translate.x * scaleOutsideX - poly1Translate.x) + halfStrokeWidth);
let translateOutsideY = -((poly1Translate.y * scaleOutsideY - poly1Translate.y) + halfStrokeWidth);

polyCopy1.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${translateOutsideX} ${translateOutsideY}) scale(${scaleOutsideX} ${scaleOutsideY})`);

// stroke-alignment:inside
let scaleInsideX = 1-strokeWidth/poly2BBox.width;
let scaleInsideY = 1-strokeWidth/poly2BBox.height;
let translateInsideX = poly2Translate.x * scaleOutsideX - poly2Translate.x + halfStrokeWidth;
let translateInsideY = poly2Translate.y * scaleOutsideY - poly2Translate.y + halfStrokeWidth;

polyCopy2.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${translateInsideX} ${translateInsideY}) scale(${scaleInsideX} ${scaleInsideY})`);
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="160">
  <g id="myGroup" style="fill:rgb(45, 130, 255);" transform="translate(20 20)">
    <polygon id="myPoly0" points="0,0 100,0 100,100 0,100"></polygon>
    <polygon id="myPoly1" points="0,0 100,0 100,100 0,100"></polygon>
    <polygon id="myPoly2" points="0,0 100,0 100,100 0,100"></polygon>

    <use id="myPolyCopy0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" href="#myPoly0"></use>
    <use id="myPolyCopy1" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" href="#myPoly1"></use>
    <use id="myPolyCopy2" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" href="#myPoly2"></use>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**UPDATE**

After noticing the following comment in the Figma [website](https://www.figma.com/widget-docs/api/component-SVG/):

> Inside and outside stroke are actually implemented by doubling the stroke weight and masking the stroke by the fill. This means inside-aligned stroke will never draw strokes outside the fill and outside-aligned stroke will never draw strokes inside the fill.

I implemented a similar method using a combination of `<clipPath>` and `<mask>`

```css
.stroke {
  fill:none;
  stroke:red;
  stroke-opacity:0.5;
}  

.stroke-center {
  stroke-width:8;
}

.stroke-inout {
  stroke-width:16;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="160">
  <defs>
    <rect id="stroke-mask" width="500" height="160" fill="white"/>
  </defs>
  <g id="myGroup" style="fill:rgb(45, 130, 255);" transform="translate(20,20)">
    <polygon id="myPoly0" points="0,0 100,0 100,100 0,100" transform="translate(0,20)"></polygon>
    <polygon id="myPoly1" points="0,0 100,0 100,100 0,100" transform="translate(150,20)"></polygon>
    <polygon id="myPoly2" points="0,0 100,0 100,100 0,100" transform="translate(300,20)"></polygon>
    <mask id="mask">
      <use href="#stroke-mask"/>
      <use href="#myPoly1" fill="black"/>
    </mask>       
    
    <clipPath id="clip">
      <use href="#myPoly2"/>
    </clipPath>    
    
    <use id="myPolyCopy0" class="stroke stroke-center" href="#myPoly0"></use>
    <use id="myPolyCopy1" class="stroke stroke-inout" href="#myPoly1" mask="url(#mask)"></use>
    <use id="myPolyCopy2" class="stroke stroke-inout" href="#myPoly2" clip-path="url(#clip)"></use>    
  </g>
</svg>
```

The idea here is, to achieve the equivalent of:

1. `stroke-align:center`: is the default behavior, do nothing
2. `stroke-align:inner`: Create a `clipPath` using the source object to which you want to apply the inner stroke, then with the `<use>` element, create a copy of this with a stroke **twice the width** you actually want, and set the `clip-path` of the copy to be the `clipPath` created from the source object. This will effectively clip everything *outside* the clipPath, thereby clipping the "outside half" of the double-width stroke
3. `stroke-align:outer`: There isn't an equivalent of `clipPath` which will clip everything *inside* the path (sadly), so the way to achieve this is to use a `<mask>`, but the same principle applies as for `inner`. Create a `<mask>` based on the source object, create a copy with a double-width stroke, then use the mask to clip everything inside the mask, thereby clipping the "inside half" of the double-width stroke

Comment: I generally find it easier to read transforms as transformations of the **coordinate system**. Read them left-to-right and down the DOM tree, and draw a new coordinate system each time. If you want to describe it as a transformation of the grafic, read them right-to-left and up the DOM tree.

Comment: I just noted this on the Figma website:

"Inside and outside stroke are actually implemented by doubling the stroke weight and masking the stroke by the fill. This means inside-aligned stroke will never draw strokes outside the fill and outside-aligned stroke will never draw strokes inside the fill."

https://www.figma.com/widget-docs/api/component-SVG/

I may attempt a variation the approach in this SO post using a clip mask. Will post back with a solution if I do